# Liquid - Nested "where" filter

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

Is it possible to use the `| where` filter on an array such as a cart line item object to filter by property value.

For example, I would like to find all line items with property._design_id of 123.
As far as I can see you're able to filter `array | 'type', 'Coat'`, but not something like `array | 'properties._design_id', '123'`.

I am aware that I could alternatively do this with a for loop & if statements, however that's a few more lines of code & I would be able to reuse the array without recomputing each time I needed to use those items.

Comment: Potentially, I'd seen the question but it was old & I was hoping that things had changed/alternative solutions had been discovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This currently seems impossible as liquid compares exact keys & values not keys for nested arrays.

https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/f1846d63a32f006cddf4b2d968ef4e552a9ccc94/lib/liquid/standardfilters.rb#L411

Current work around is:

```ruby
for item in cart.items
    if item.properties._design_id === '123'
         code...
    endif
endfor
```