# Liquid - Filter Array Of Products Using Properties

Tags: shopify, liquid

I would like to filter an array of products using values from the `properties` field. Specifically so in the cart with `line_items`.

I am currently trying to use the `where` filter, to only include products with the property of "group-id". Ideally, this would be as easy as:

```
{% assign filtered_items = items | where: 'properties.group-id' %}
```

But from trying this, and searching around in the documentation and online, it doesn't look like others were able to get it to work.

- [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57748892/is-it-possible-to-use-a-liquid-where-array-filter-with-nested-properties)
- [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73371741/liquid-nested-where-filter)

Jekyll looks to have a `where_exp` [filter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/#:%7E:text=where%3A%22graduation_year%22%2C%222014%22%20%7D%7D-,Where%20Expression,-Select%20all%20the) which would be able to solve this nested issue if it were a part of Shopify Liquid.

I understand this can be implemented using a for loop with conditional checks,  but I am curious about the possibility this method.

Comment: You can't map by nested properties in shopify, just loop and create a new array, no other solution for now

Comment: @Alopwer That's what I ended up doing as well. Wish they had the `where_exp` filter like Jekyll, but it works for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to use the [`where`](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/where) filter as I was hoping, but ended up solving the issue anyway.

In my use case, I needed to create sub-arrays based on a common property. This common property always showed up contiguously across items in the original array.

This made the situation a little easier. I ended up iterating through the original array, kept track of the relevant indices, and took slices of it using [`slice`](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/slice) to create the sub-arrays.